# RSpec 'change': Braces or brackets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am following Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial and there is an RSpec testing code snippet:

```
expect do
 click_button 'Follow'
end.to change(user.followed_users, :count).by(1)`
```

According to the [RSpec documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-change) and how I learned on [Codeschool](http://rspec.codeschool.com/levels/2), this should really be:

```
expect do
 click_button 'Follow'
end.to change {user.followed_users.count}.by(1)
```

Obviously they are both valid, but there seems to be no documentation for the first way of doing the change matcher in the RSpec documentation and I am wondering why/how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find it in the Relish documentation either, but RSpec is open source after all, so let's dig in.  In [the current version of the change matcher](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/change.rb):

```
module RSpec
  module Matchers
    module BuiltIn
      class Change
        def initialize(receiver=nil, message=nil, &block)
          @message = message
          @value_proc = block || lambda {receiver.__send__(message)}
          @expected_after = @expected_before = @minimum = @maximum = @expected_delta = nil
          @eval_before = @eval_after = false
        end
```

It's all about `@value_proc`.  If you supply a block, it uses that; and if you don't supply a block, it makes a new lambda that sends the second argument to the first argument.  If you read through the source a little more, you'll see the `#matches?` method, which contains:

```
@actual_before = evaluate_value_proc
event_proc.call
@actual_after = evaluate_value_proc
```

where `evaluate_value_proc` mainly does `@value_proc.call`.

I think that "conventional" RSpec would have you supply an explicit block.  The two-argument approach might make more sense if you're metaprogramming, but even then, you *could* use the block approach and call `send` yourself.

Comment: "it makes a new lambda" - sorry I am unfamiliar with Lambda's: are they the same as named parameters? If so then I think I understand. It looks like it takes 1 or 2 parameters in that case, is that right? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[**Documentation**](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers#change-instance_method) for the **#change** method found in **rubydoc.info.**
It explains that you can use either a block or the `receiver` and `message` arguments. You can check the examples provided in the page.